# How to realize a very big int matrix with 5 string columns in numpy (python3)?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I don't know how to solve my problem. I need a very big matrix (2.000.000 x 20.000) filled with zeros (int). And I need to add 5 columns with strings to that matrix.

I thought a good solution is to use numpy, because it can handle big arrays and it is very fast. The first thing I did is to create a zero-matrix

```
np_array = numpy.zeros((20000, 2000000), dtype=int)
```

And it works very well and fast. But now I need to save the matrix to csv and the csv need 5 additional columns which contain strings. 
What is the best way to do it? And can it be saved this way:

```
numpy.savetxt("test.csv", np_array, delimiter=",", fmt='%d')
```

I would be very happy if someone could help me. If you have a better idea how to solve the problem (to use something else than numpy) please don't hesitate and write it :)

With kind regards,
Oli

Comment: Do you need this matrix just to create the csv file?

Comment: No, I work with the matrix. When it is done, I need to save the matrix to csv, and than I load the csv in R to visualize the data.

Comment: Your life will be a lot simpler if you keep the integer and text arrays separate.  It's one thing to have a `csv` file with 10 columns of mixed int, float and string types, and quite another to have on with 2 million int columns followed by 5 string columns.

Comment: If your goal is just to get the data into a format that R can read then I would suggest using a binary format rather than `.csv`. Binary formats are much more efficient in terms of storage space, and are usually faster to read and write to. One option might be save the integers and strings separately in numpy's native `.npy` format using `numpy.save`, then use the [`RcppCNPy`](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.cnpy.html) package to read them into R.

Comment: Tnak you ali_m. I will try that. Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` allows mixed `dtypes`.  `genfromtxt` and `loadtxt` create those when loading columns of mixed types.

```
dt = np.dtype([('f0',int),('f1',int),('f2','S10')])
x = np.zeros((4,), dtype=dt)
```

produces an array with 4 records; each record consists of a 2 ints and one string.  `x['f0']` gives an array of 4 ints, the first field of `x`, etc.  `np.savetxt` easily saves this sort of array.

```
np.savetxt('test.txt',x,fmt='%d %d %s')
```

But with thousands of columns that is impractical.  Plus you can't perform much math across columns.

Fields can have multiple terms:

```
dt=np.dtype([('f0','int',(10,)),('f1','S4',(3,))])
```

With this `x['f0']` would be a `(n,10)` array of integers, `x['f1']` a  `(n,3)` of 4 character strings.

But saving that is a bit trickier

```
In [77]: np.savetxt('test.txt',A,fmt='%s')

In [78]: cat test.txt
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ['ones' 'ones' 'ones']
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ['ones' 'ones' 'ones']
...
```

`np.savetxt` isn't that complicated.  It just expands the `fmt` to one that works with:

```
for row in A:
   print fmt%tuple(row)
```

But I'm not aware of a `fmt` that would display that without the brackets.  But maybe you can construct your own line write that does what you want.

---

I should add that appending these text columns to your integer array will, probably, slow down use of the integers.  Instead of having a `NxM` array of integers, data is now `M` integers, followed by a set of strings, followed by another `M` integers, etc.

---

Here's a way of writing the 2 field array in csv format.  As with `savetxt` I am iterating through the rows (records) of the array.  But here I format the 2 fields separately, and then join them for the write.  I could have used `%s` to format the strings, but `join` works just as well.  I think this will work just as fast as `savetxt`.

```
with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    fmt0 = ['%d']*10  # or a['f0'].shape[0]
    for a in A:
        strs = (','.join(fmt0 % tuple(a['f0']), ', '.join(a['f1']))
        astr = '%s; %s\n'%strs   # different delimiter just for effect
        f.write(astr)
```

producing

```
In [121]: cat test.txt
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; ones, ones, ones
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; ones, ones, ones
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; ones, ones, ones
....
```

Actually I wouldn't even have to join the int array and string array into one structured array.  I could simply iterate through two such arrays separately.  Writing them shouldn't take much longer than writing just one.

```
In [122]: A0,A1=A['f0'],A['f1']
In [123]: with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    for a,b in zip(A0,A1):
        strs = (','.join(['%d']*10)%tuple(a),', '.join(b))
        astr = '%s; %s\n'%strs
        f.write(astr)
```

---

`pandas` `csv` reader has a reputation for being faster than the `numpy` `genfromtxt`, but I have seen any such claims for `df.to_csv`.  This function is implemented in `pandas.core.format.py`.  It looks like it uses the `Python` `csv.writer`, calling `writer.writerow(row_fields)` for each line.  I haven't compared the `csv.writer` with `numpy.savetxt`, but I suspect their writing speeds are comparable.

So any route, saving a very large text file will be slow.

---

I suspect that formatting a very long list of integers is the slowest step of writing to a file.

```
In [145]: timeit s=(','.join(['%d']*1000))%tuple(np.arange(1000))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 ms per loop

In [146]: %%timeit fmt=','.join(['%d']*1000)
s=fmt%tuple(np.arange(1000))
   .....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 ms per loop  # making fmt isn't expensive

In [147]: timeit s=str(np.arange(1000).tolist())[1:-1]
10000 loops, best of 3: 162 us per loop
```

In this last case I use the default formatting for a list.

Array formatting is actually slower - I think that's because it goes to the extra work of breaking the display into lines.

```
In [152]: timeit s=str(np.arange(1000))[1:-1]
100 loops, best of 3: 11.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: At the moment I am joining two strings (5 string columns and the matrix), but it takes about 100-120 seconds for one line. If I only save the matrix it only takes about 1h for the whole matrix. So it is a big difference. Bob Baxley's solution is great for a small corpus, but if I run the big corpus, than I don't know if it freezes when I am trying to write the strings or if it simpy takes 1h to write only one line. It is very strange. I am very new to numpy und R. I am for every idea very thankful :)

Comment: I just did some time tests on alternative ways to format a long array of ints.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is the module you want to use when you start needing to make numpy arrays of mixed types.

I tried solving your problem a few different ways and they are all pretty slow for 20000, 2000000 matrices.  But if you can tolerate the time or you have a slightly smaller problem, something like this will work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np_array = np.zeros((20000, 20005),dtype=int)
df = pd.DataFrame(np_array)
df[[0,1,2,3,4]] = "Hello World"
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

I am basically making 5 extra columns, converting the array to a pandas dataframe and then adding the text using to the first 5 columns of the dataframe.

Comment: At the moment I need about 10 min to create the final matrix and about 1h to write it to the disk. I will try your solution and get back to you.

Comment: Well for a small corpus it is working fine. But if I run the whole corpus it isn't working. It simply freezes when I am trying to assign the first string. The same code works for a smaller corpus, very strange.